# Normalizing a monotonically increasing function and calculate std

Tags: python, statistics, analytics

I have an increasing function like so:

[image]

I plan on breaking it up into intervals (between the red lines).
I want to rotate the segment horizontal and calculate the standard deviation.

I know this might seem silly, but I essentially want to calculate the variation after normalizing the increasing ramp per segment.
What method can I use to achieve this?

My initial thoughts are to take calculate the slope and draw a line from the beginning to the end of the segment with that slope. Then, calculate the delta of each data point with respect to the
line.

Comment: I don't see much code there and this site is about fixing issues with code...  That said, what form does your function take?  Is it a set of data points, something algebraic, something else?  Not sure how to answer your question without these details

Comment: @SamMason I’m not looking for code as such. I’m more looking for an algorithm suggestion. 

The data is a set of data points that results in part of the plot shown in the pic

Comment: Why not just fit a linear regression to the interval, that would seem to give you everything you need.

Comment: @SamMason, that might work. So in that case, would the SSR be the variance between each data point wrt the fitted line? Or would I have to deconstruct the SSR so that I can calculate std/variance from the residuals? I plan to use Python for this.

Comment: you could just use [scipy's linregress](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html) to get parameter estimates (i.e. slope and intercept), then just calculate the variance using that.  you could use something fancier like https://www.statsmodels.org/ if you want which might be slightly easier, but would have more overhead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had quick play with writing some code.  I grabbed some numbers from your sketched function using https://apps.automeris.io/wpd/, giving me:

```
csvdata = """\
x,y
22937.2,1822.1
22942.9,1822.2
22950.0,1822.4
22959.6,1822.5
22967.8,1822.5
22976.8,1822.6
22987.1,1822.6
22995.5,1822.7
23004.7,1822.7
23014.1,1822.7
23025.1,1822.7
23034.2,1822.8
23043.1,1822.9
23049.8,1823.0
23057.9,1823.2
23064.0,1823.3
23070.0,1823.5
23078.7,1823.6
23086.6,1823.7
23096.3,1823.9
23104.0,1824.0
23112.9,1824.1
23122.6,1824.1
23131.5,1824.1
23141.3,1824.1
23153.3,1824.0
23164.6,1824.1
"""
```

Then I got that data into Python using Pandas, performed the regression I suggested and plot the output using:

```
from io import StringIO

import numpy as np
import scipy.stats
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# get data
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csvdata))

# basic univariate linear regression
res = scipy.stats.linregress(df.x, df.y)
print(res)

# estimate y at each x
yp = res.intercept + df.x * res.slope
# calculate standard error
sd = np.std(yp - df.y)

plt.plot(df.x, df.y, label="function")
plt.plot(df.x, yp, label="slope that minimises residual")
plt.title(f"SD of residual = {sd:.2f}")
plt.legend()
```

giving me:

[image: matplotlib output]

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for! 
I’m guessing I can also calculate variance with `np.var(yp -df.y)` ?

Comment: yup, sounds right.  note that these are [student's t](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) distributed not normally due to data previously being used to calculate the parameters